# how to edit .globalpreferences.plist without logout and login?

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to make a kiosk application on my Mac. I want to disable certain hotkeys which can be done by editing the `.globalprefernces.plist` file but it requires a re-login to the system which I do not want, similar to the System preferences application.

Thanks in advance,

Amit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to edit that file (and should not) to make a kiosk application.

See [-[NSApplication setPresentationOptions]](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/setPresentationOptions:).  This includes the following options:

```
   NSApplicationPresentationDefault                    = 0,
   NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideDock               = (1 <<  0),
   NSApplicationPresentationHideDock                   = (1 <<  1),
   NSApplicationPresentationAutoHideMenuBar            = (1 <<  2),
   NSApplicationPresentationHideMenuBar                = (1 <<  3),
   NSApplicationPresentationDisableAppleMenu           = (1 <<  4),
   NSApplicationPresentationDisableProcessSwitching    = (1 <<  5),
   NSApplicationPresentationDisableForceQuit           = (1 <<  6),
   NSApplicationPresentationDisableSessionTermination  = (1 <<  7),
   NSApplicationPresentationDisableHideApplication     = (1 <<  8),
   NSApplicationPresentationDisableMenuBarTransparency = (1 <<  9)
```

See also [Guide to Creating Kiosks on Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2062.html).  That discusses the Carbon API for kiosks (which may or may not be available in 64 bit, I didn't check), but there's a clear mapping onto the Cocoa API above.